# How to find an object in a list by comparing on object property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How could I scan an array of objects in order to find an object by matching the object property:

```
$scope.items = [
  { id: 1, name: 'one' }, 
  { id: 2, name: 'two' }, 
  { id: 3, name: 'three' }
];

$scope.item = $scope.items.find({ id: 1 }); // pseudo-code
```

Comment: At 4kb, underscore.js would be the -easiest- solution to this: http://underscorejs.org/

Comment: is there any function in anguler js to find(object) like push(object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Used [Underscore js](http://underscorejs.org/)

```
$scope.item = _.where($scope.items, { id: 1 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular's built-in filter functionality to perform the search:

```
$scope.filteredItems = function() {
    return $filter($scope.items, id == filterID);
}
```

Here is a fiddle showing the filter in action: http://jsfiddle.net/wittersworld/xV8QT/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method like this:

```
$scope.items.filter(function (item) {
    return item.id === 1; }
)
```